# Create a table in SQL where the Composite Primary Key is also a Foreign Key

Tags: sql, oracle11g, foreign-keys, oracle-sqldeveloper, composite-key

I need to create a table called LFM_Enroll in SQL that has a composite primary key of Student_ID and Section_Number. Student_ID is also a foreign key, it references Student_ID in the LFM_Student table and Section_Number is also a foreign key, it references Section_Number in the LFM_Section table. How do I write the constraints and foreign keys? I've attached an image of the tables and below is what I have done so far. After the LFM_Enroll table is created I need to update one row. I tried doing so but kept getting the below error.

```html
: Error starting at line : 173 in command -
UPDATE LFM_Enroll
SET Student_ID = 1234567,
    Section_Number = 01234
WHERE Student_ID = 900000 AND Section_Number =  4138
Error report -
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SYSTEM.FK_LFM_ENROLL_SECTION_NUMBER) violated - parent key not found.
```

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fc6Hv.png) Thanks in advance for all your help.

```html
CREATE TABLE LFM_Enroll (
    Student_ID         char(7),
    Section_Number     char(4),
    constraint PK_LFM_Enroll Primary Key (Student_ID,Section_Number),
    constraint FK_LFM_Enroll_Student_ID
      Foreign Key (Student_ID,Section_Number) references LFM_Student (Student_ID),
    constraint FK_LFM_Enroll_Section_Number
      Foreign Key (Student_ID,Section_Number) references LFM_Section (Section_Number)
      
    );
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: oracle sql developer

Comment: Oracle Express 11g

Answer (score 2):

Your foreign key constraints are not right. You are trying to map two columns {`Student_ID`,`Section_Number`} to a single column `LFM_Student.Student_ID`.

The number of columns in the principal key must match the number of columns in the foreign key. In other words, the key `LFM_Student` is one column (`Student_ID`), so the foreign key also needs to be a single matching column - in this case `LFM_Enroll.Student_ID`. Correct DDL would be:

```
constraint FK_LFM_Enroll_Student_ID
  Foreign Key (Student_ID) references LFM_Student (Student_ID),
constraint FK_LFM_Enroll_Section_Number
  Foreign Key (Section_Number) references LFM_Section (Section_Number)
```

---

I'm not quite sure why your RDBMS is allowing what you have, but it may be using the first column and simply ignoring the second. In which case `FK_LFM_Enroll_Section_Number` is creating a foreign key `LFM_Enroll.Student_ID` => `LFM_Section.Section_Number`.

Comment: Thank you I tried that and it worked. I do have values inserted into all tables, including the 900000 and 4138. I ran the update command but still getting an error:Error starting at line : 173 in command -
UPDATE LFM_Enroll
SET Student_ID = 1234567,
    Section_Number = 01234
WHERE Student_ID = 900000 AND Section_Number =  4138
Error report -
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SYSTEM.FK_LFM_ENROLL_SECTION_NUMBER) violated - parent key not found

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the values with which you are trying to update the two columns may not exist in Student and / or Sections tables i.e. `1234567` doesn't exists in the student table and / or `01234` doesn't exist in your section table . You should try inserting new rows or updating existing ones with the new values you are trying to update your foreign keys with.

[**Edit:** For defining constraints refer lc.'s post]

Comment: Typically that's definitely correct, but I think the problem here goes a little deeper. See my answer.

Comment: Agree... but what I think that the rdbms will not allow the values in the enroll table in the first place with that constraint definition...not sure

Comment: And I just found the image link in the question, with data. I think we have two simultaneous issues...it was throwing on `FK_LFM_Enroll_Section_Number` and I assumed the update would be with valid values; apparently not the case.

Comment: Right...it could be